# htmlagilitypack xpath not working

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a problem that my xpath is not working.

I am trying to get the url of Google.com's next link at the bottom.

But i am unable to reach on url using Xpath.

Please help me in correcting my xpath. Also tell me what should be on the place of ??

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=seo");
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='pnnext']");

foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.Attributes["href"];
    MessageBox.Show(link.Value );
}
```

Comment: The XPath seems OK. I don't see any `??`

Comment: But it is not returning any result

Comment: yes, the linknodes is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>The weird thing here is that somehow HtmlAgilityPack does not recognize the `id` attribute of the "Next" link.</s>

This could be a bug in HtmlAgilityPack; you can post it in the [HAP Issue Tracker](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

However, in the meantime I found this workaround:

- find the table that contains the paging elements (the table with `id="nav"`). For this element the id is correctly recognized
- take the first (and only `tr`) in the table and the last `td` of it (using the XPath `last()` function)
- take the `a` element inside the `td` we obtained at the previous step.

Long story short, here's the code:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=seo");

var nextLink = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='nav']/tr/td[last()]/a");

Console.WriteLine(nextLink.GetAttribute("href", "err"));
```

---

#### Update

After Simon's comment I checked this again and the conclusion is that this is not a bug in HTML Agility Pack; the `id="pnnext"` attribute is only present when the request is made by a browser (perhaps depending on the *UserAgent* header value). When doing an `HttpWebRequest` from code, this is how the "Next" link appears in the output:

```
<a href="/search?q=seo&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp[...]" style="text-align:left">
```

Comment: Just to point out, it is recommended to use `.GetAttribute("href", "error")` instead of `.Attributes["href"].Value`

Comment: If you do a view source in a browser, you will see an id with 'pnnext', but there is no 'pnnext' id in the result saved from a GET from http://www.google.com/search?q=seo (for some google mysterious reason). This explains why it's not found. It's not a bug.

Comment: @SimonMourier it gets even more weird: the `id` attribute is only present when the request is done via a browser (I checked with Chrome & Fiddler). So, it's no bug in HAP; I've updated my answer. BTW, thank you for this great library! :)